Verifying a Joomla user's password in php script
Would the following be the/a correct way to verify a user's password in a php script within Joomla 5?
use Joomla\CMS\User\UserHelper as uhelp;
$verified = uhelp::verifyPassword($password, $hash, $userId);

— assuming, of course that the variable $password, $hash and $userid have been populated with the appropriate values.
One interesting observation with the verifyPassword function in the UserHelper class is that it uses a lot of deprecated hash functions. Is this a problem?

That's what's used throughout Joomla. It's fine if you don't mind using statics in your code.
The method supports deprecated algorithms so users with very old password hashes could still login. When calling this method with $userId argument, the user's password is rehashed upon successful verification. Once support for old hashes are dropped, users who haven't logged in since BCrypt passwords were introduced won't be able to login without resetting their password.
There is one more thing to mention just in case someone is using custom hashing options. It's possible for this method to reduce the strength of an existing hash. This is because it uses default options for rehash checking and rehashing. So in case you programmatically save an user with higher password cost:
$user->password = $bcryptHandler->hashPassword($password, ['cost' => 15]);
$user->save();

Calling UserHelper::verifyPassword() at any point later is actually going to rehash the password using the default cost (10 on PHP 8.3 and lower, 12 since PHP 8.4).

Thank you, Sharky, that is very helpful, as always. I really appreciate your generosity with your time.
